GAM: Smooth and factor interaction
I am currently working on a GAM. It includes a smooth-factor interaction. I am trying to decide which function is the one I need.
Model_gamlog2 <- mgcv::gam(perpetration_all ~ dar_scale + s(dar_scale, by = age_binary) + age_binary, data = merged_all_complete, family=binomial, method = "REML")

> summary(Model_gamlog2)

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
perpetration_all ~ dar_scale + s(dar_scale, by = age_binary) + 
    age_binary

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.7862     0.3707   4.818 1.45e-06 ***
dar_scale    -0.2610     7.0429  -0.037    0.970    
age_binary2   1.7874     1.2895   1.386    0.166    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                           edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value
s(dar_scale):age_binary1 1.000  1.000  0.010   0.920
s(dar_scale):age_binary2 1.474  2.122  2.038   0.421

Rank: 20/21
R-sq.(adj) =  0.0173   Deviance explained = 9.94%
-REML = 39.827  Scale est. = 1         n = 134

Here I use the By= argument.
I have some questions regarding this output:

Do I need s() as smoothing parameter or are ti() etc. also possible. I just want the smoothing parameters for each level of IV to vary if needed.
How do I see whether there is an interaction? As far as I understand smooth terms only tell me that per level of IV age there is no significant correlation to DV, not whether they differ.

Alternatively I have the following code:
Model_gamlog2 <- mgcv::gam(perpetration_all ~ dar_scale + s(dar_scale, age_binary, bs = "fs") + age_binary, data = merged_all_complete, family=binomial, method = "REML")

> summary(Model_gamlog2)

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
perpetration_all ~ dar_scale + s(dar_scale, age_binary, bs = "fs") + 
    age_binary

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.8761     0.3907   4.802 1.57e-06 ***
dar_scale     0.5246     0.4452   1.178   0.2386    
age_binary2   1.2737     0.7561   1.685   0.0921 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                          edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value
s(dar_scale,age_binary) 3.346     17  5.558   0.125

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0508   Deviance explained = 13.9%
-REML = 42.792  Scale est. = 1         n = 134

Does s(dar_scale,age_binary) show the interaction effect?

By interaction effect, what specifically are you trying to capture with your model? Are you just trying to see how the association between dar_scale and perpetration_all looks between ages? Also, what is the nature of the age_binary variable? The naming seems to convey it has been dichotomized in some way, but there is not much to go off of in the question.

Yes the interaction is between dar, which measures anger dysregulation, and the age groups. I dichotomised age with a median split.

What Not to Do
I will start by saying that it is generally not wise to dichotomize a numeric variable. Generally it results in a loss of information and produces bias in your standard errors. It also just doesn't make sense to do if you are trying to get a realistic approximation of how age works, particularly when age is likely to have nonlinear effects on the outcome anyway. As an example, I have seen in my own work that age has a nonlinear effect on word reading ability in Chinese, where students who get older tend to stop improving in reading ability and need to be tested on more complex reading skills (e.g. reading comprehension). Binning this data would cause some problems. You can see a simulated example below:
#### Simulate Data ####
set.seed(123)
n <- 300
age <- runif(n,0,6)
Read <- log(age) + rnorm(n,40,sd=.5)
Age <- age + 6

#### Plot ####
plot(
  Age,
  Read,
  main="Age and Word Reading",
  pch=21,
  bg="gray"
  )

The plotted data shows that age seems associated with initial increases in reading, but then rapidly declines after around 7 or 8 years old.

Now suppose we bin this data and plot it again:
#### Visualize ####
bin.age <- ifelse(Age > mean(Age),1,0)

plot(
  jitter(bin.age,factor = .1),
  Read,
  xlab="Age",
  pch=21,
  bg="gray",
  main="Binned Age by Reading"
  )


Now we have completely lost the nonlinear trend, and its not clear now why one group varies a lot more than the other (without knowing how this data was generated).
What to Do
Now as far as what you can do instead, I would suggest running the same model with age as continuous, but fit it as a main effect and interaction like so:
gam(
  perpetration_all # DV
  ~ s(dar_scale) # main effect smooth of scale
  + s(age) # main effect smooth of age
  + ti(dar_scale, age), # interaction between age and dar scale
  data = merged_all_complete, # data
  family=binomial, # using binomial family
  method = "REML" # restricted maximum likelihood estimation
  )

The s() function fits an independent smooth to each predictor, and ti() creates an interaction between age and your other predictor after conditioning for the main effects. When plotting, you should get back a regression line for each main effect, and a 3D plot of the interaction between them. Importantly, I have removed the linear effect you added to the model (where it was just listed as dar_scale), as this just fits a linear trend (when you already have a smooth in the model).
Edit
Per the comments, ti() is usually used for smooth interactions between multiple continuous variables and won't produce any plots if you don't have s() fitted main effects anyway (because there is nothing to build without them). The bs = "fs" argument in a typical s() smooth creates a smooth where each level of a factor shares the same smoothing parameter and is in a sense like the smooth version of random slopes. (See additional edit below).
The s() function fits an independent smooth to each predictor, and ti() creates an interaction between age and your other predictor after conditioning for the main effects. When plotting, you should get back a regression line for each main effect, and a 3D plot of the interaction between them. Importantly, I have removed the linear effect you added to the model (where it was just listed as dar_scale), as this just fits a linear trend (when you already have a smooth in the model).
Edit 2
To clarify, the ti() function can be used as both a main effect and interaction. It is however often used to construct interactions in the following way, where the s()/ti() function with a single variable estimates a main effect (by default thin plate regression splines for s() and cubic regression for ti()), and the combined variables in ti() create a separate interaction like the : operator in regular regressions in R.
s(x) + s(z) + ti(s,z)

Consequently, the model can also be constructed as so, where the ti() version has a smooth that is a tensor product but of a single marginal smooth (per Gavin's comments below):
ti(x) + ti(z) + ti(s,z)

Either one works and one can also just fit the interactions by themselves (if that is the goal). The by= argument simply fits a regression line to each level of a factor variable, so that if you have three levels in a factor, the spline produces three separate lines for each. The bs = "fs" argument instead estimates a smooth in the way I described earlier. I will note again that the by = and bs="fs" arguments in a smooth shouldn't apply in this case given you shouldn't be estimating different factors of dichotomized age. While one can compare differences between by-smooths, it shouldn't really apply here.

Thank you very much. I did run this model before. Unfortunately, I had high concurvity. And as this is just a hypothesis generating analyses (I do not have many participants) I thought of adding another model to the appendix where age is dichotomised. That was done before with this variables.

While trying to do so, I realised that I don´t quite understand how an interaction between a smooth and factor is done in gam. As shown before, by= results in smooths for every factor level but where is the interaction? And s() with 2 variables usually (as fas as I understood) does not discriminate between main effect and interaction. In a glm I would only get the interaction for one factor level with the continuous variable and would need to look further into the interaction effect. Here, I am a bit lost.

The only thing that by= does is create a smooth regression line for each level of your factor variable. In that sense it is a bit like a nonlinear version of an interaction between a continuous and categorical variable, but I assume your issue is statistically testing a difference of smooths. One could perhaps fit a model with a simple age-only smooth and compare it to a by-factor smooth model and see if the LRT test or AIC values differ appreciably if that is the goal, though this only tests the term itself and not each smooth from each other.

Thank you! I was just thinking, would this be applicable if I only want the interaction: ti(dar_scale, age_binary, bs = "fs"? This would use the tensor interaction (excludes the main effects) with a smoothing for the factor levels.

Your description of ti() in the edit is incorrect; if one does ti(x) you will get s(x). If you fit a model with y ~ ti(x,z) you will get the pure interaction effect and it will produce a plot - in the same way that y ~ x:z also doesn't do nothing. It is preferable to use ti(x) + ti(z) + ti(x,z) over s(x) + s(z) + ti(x,z) because s() and ti() have different default spline basis.

I actually didn't realize that ti() has a different default basis. Is my understanding correct that s() uses a thin plate regression spline by default, while ti() uses a cubic regression spline by default? I can amend my answer accordingly @GavinSimpson. Before editing my answer, I tried using just ti(x,y) as a test and it didn't work. That was more what I was hinting at and not the function by itself.

Thank you all very much. I take it that I can´t simply have a term which shows the interaction between a smooth and a factor variable. Am I correct in this assumption? And if s() with the bs="fs" is significant, what does it tell me? That at least one of the smooths is significant or something else?

@GavinSimpson: Would you recommend ti(x)+ti(y)+ti(x,y) or s(x, bs="cr")+s(y, bs="cr")+ti(x,y)? (Only for continuous variables)

@Laura You most certainly can have a term that is the interaction between a smooth and a factor - see ?mgcv::factor.smooth for the options available in mgcv for this. Shawn's main point however is well-made; you should avoid dichotomising a continuous variable.

@ShawnHemelstrand I should have been clearer: y ~ ti(x, k = 10) should give the same model fit as y ~ s(x, bs = "cr", k = 10) (the internal structures are different; the ti() version has a smooth that is a tensor product but of a single marginal smooth). y ~ ti(x,z) is most certainly valid and can be plotted: gam(y ~ ti(x,z, k = c(10,10)), data = gratia::data_sim("eg2", seed = 2, n = 1000)) |> plot(). Yes s() uses a TPRS by default.

@Laura I really don't think it matters; just note that in this ti(x)+ti(y)+ti(x,y) the univariate ti() will have fewer EDF than the one with unvariate s() because not only is the bs argument different by default, the default heuristics for k are also different. The default for ti() and te() is 5^d where d is the number of margins in the tensor product; Hence ti(x) will get a basis with 5 functions while s(x) will have 10 (in both cases before any identifiability constraints are applied).

@GavinSimpson: I should have also ben clearer. I am struggling to comprehend how the option R suggests can help in my case. I want to see whether the interaction between the continuous variable and the factor (does the relation between x and y depend on the level of z) is significant. With by=I only get the relation between x and y for every level of z but not whether they differ from each other. So I questioned whether this gives me the pure interaction or again a mixture of main and interaction effects: s(x,z,bs="fs").

@GavinSimpson: Thank you very much for your time. I think I get somewhere.

I am a bit confused regarding the use of ti() with or without s()in one function. My model for both continuous variables with another DV is as following: gam(variety_factor ~ dar_scale + age_scale + ti(dar_scale, age_scale),family = ocat(R = 6), data = merged_all_complete). The results for ti() are more or less similar to the results I get from this model, where I did not specify the smooths of the main effect: gam(variety_factor ~ ti(dar_scale) + ti(age_scale) + ti(dar_scale, age_scale), family = ocat(R = 6), data = merged_all_complete)

@GavinSimpson thanks for clarifying. I think that was already essentially my understanding without the clear differences you point out. I have changed my answer to reflect that.

Adding to previous comment: Here both predictors on their own have a edf of 1, suggesting linearity. Only the interaction term is non-linear.

@GavinSimpson may be able to speak more on that, but as far as it is my understanding, there is no stopping anyone from fitting linear effects directly while also estimating their interaction as nonlinear. Though I'm curious as to why the interaction is nonlinear.

@Shawn unfortunately I do not know. Those are preliminary data with only a few participants in a topic that has not much research till now. Maybe I can find an explanation. For now it is more exploration.

I thought I understood it now that s(x,z,bs="fs") includes both main effects and interaction but when I tested this model: perpetration_all ~ s(dar_scale, age_binary, bs = "fs") against one with only main effects: perpetration_all ~ dar_scale + age_binary the one with only main effects had a lower AIC. Shouldn´t the one which includes both effects be lower or at least the same?

@Laura while there's nothing stopping you modelling the main effects as linear, i) in this case you only knew they were linear because you fitted a model where you allowed them to be non-linear (so any further inference is biased in the wrong way), ii) if you think the interaction is non-linear, I would argue that there is no sensible scientific reason to model the main effects as linear; model them as smooths and if the estimated effect is linear, just live with it.

@Laura re your last comment, those models that you're comparing aren't even close to being a "main effects" and a "main effect plus interaction" model. The AIC is being corrected to account for smoothing parameter selection (which isn't happening in the "main effects" model as there are no smooths) for one thing, and the group means in the fs model are being estimated as a random effects (and hence have some bias which might affect a prediction-based IC), and the fs model also includes random slopes per group, i.e. way more parameters, which AIC is penalizing you for.

@GavinSimpson: Thanks again! Then I will calculate a model with all factors as smooths. Problem is that I have high concurvity but I will just live with that (I mean it is only exploratory).

@GavinSimpson: I am still trying to understand fs. If this is significant, can I conclude that the interaction is significant? If yes, then that is all I need. And thanks again for your detailed response.

@Laura The test for the fs smooth is purely one where the null hypothesis is that all the subject specific smooths are constant (horizontal) functions and the deviation of the group means about 0 is equal to 0 (no deviation). You really shouldn't be doing statistics the way your question/comment implies you are. It doesn't matter if this term is or is not statistically significant. What matters is whether the estimated effects are biological (or scientifically) relevant.
